# Widget Of Awesomeness, an extended profile JavaScript widget

Tags: app, javascript, widget

2010-07-17: **Due to lack of interest I'm shutting down the hosted version of this.**

### Screenshots

Widget:

[image]

### About

The Widget Of Awesomeness lets you embed a simple widget on any page that will display your awesome activity on any Stack Exchange site.

By following three easy steps, you can have a [Widget Of Awesomeness](http://www.ioncannon.net/projects/woa/configure.php) of your own.

#### Change Log

The following is a short list of the main features added with each release.

**Version 1.0**

- Initial release

#### License

MIT

#### Platform

I've tested the configuration and widget on a number of browsers. Please let me know if something seems off; include the browser type and version in the report.

### Contact

Send me an email, to woa@ioncannon.net, if something doesn't seem to work correctly .

### Source

Find [it on GitHub](http://github.com/carsonmcdonald/WOA).

Comment: Really neat - I gotta try this out.

Comment: Uh... on Chrome 5.0.375.70 beta on Ubuntu I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'supersubs'   master.min.js:13`.

Comment: @George Edison Is that causing something to break for you? That looks like it is part of the theme javascript.

Comment: @carson: I get that when I click on the "This is me - Step 2" thing after searching for my name. And no, nothing happens when I click so I can't even use the widget at all.

Comment: @George Edison I couldn't repeat getting stuck but I did see the error. I changed things a little and got the error in question to go away. I also added some more error handling so hopefully between those two things it fixes the issue.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work. JavaScript error: '$' is null or not an object Line: 152  har: 1 Code: 0.  when trying to search for a user name.

Comment: @Magnus Sorry about that. Nobody seemed to want to use it so I didn't update it. I'm going to shut the hosted version down. The code is on github if you want to run it yourself.

Comment: you could hold out until a dedicated 'app-store' solution is arrived at and traffic is driven to it (hopefully)